# Editing ace code editor does not work when a code fragment is inserted into swiper-slide from Swiperjs. What to do?

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

It starts working as soon as I take it outside the swiper-slide.

I tried to add many options of swiperJs, it doesnt work. The code fragment itself is displayed as it should, but editing and clicking on a line of code doesnt work